# Automate Asgard next group creation

Tags: continuous-deployment, amazon-ami, netflix, asgard

Is there a way to automate creating the next asgard auto scaling group? I have the AMI image ID I want to deploy with. I poked around their API and it doesn't seem clear to me how this can be done.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here I've solved this using some simple shell scripts. You can wrap this up in any REST api or language you want, but the gist is

- Query the prepare endpoint for your cluster and include the environment. This gives you the current launch configuration + the list of all AMI's for that cluster
- Get the last ami in the list since its sorted ascending (last ami is the most recent)
- Set the ami field of the prepare json you pulled using the new ami
- Post the new json back to the start endpoint

---

```
function asgard(){
  verb=$1
  url="https://my.asgard.com/us-east-1/$2"
  shift
  http ${VERB} --verify=no "$url" -b
}

function next-ami(){
  cluster=$1

  prepare-ami $cluster true | \
    jq ".environment.images | reverse | .[0]"
}

function prepare-ami(){
  cluster=$1

  includeEnv=$2

  asgard GET "deployment/prepare/${cluster}?deploymentTemplateName=CreateAndCleanUpPreviousAsg&includeEnvironment=${includeEnv}"
}

function get-next-ami(){
  cluster=$1

  next=`next-ami ${cluster} | jq ".id"`

  prepare-ami ${cluster} "false" | jq ".lcOptions.imageId |= ${next}"
}

function start-deployment(){
  cluster=$1
  payload=$2

  echo $payload | asgard POST "deployment/start/${cluster}"
}
```

Source post: http://onoffswitch.net/scripting-deployment-clusters-asgard/